# Pandas: Selecting multiple rows based on column pair

Tags: python, pandas

I am adapting my data analysis pipeline from a wide to the tidy/long format right now and have a problem with filtering it and I just cannot wrap my head around it.

My data (simplified) looks like this (microscopy intensity data): in each *measurement* of a *group* I have several *regions of interest = roi* where I am looking at the intensity (=*value*) over several *timepoints*.

A *roi* is basically a single cell in the microscope image. I am following the change of intensity (=*value*) over time (=*timepoint*). I repeat this experiment a couple of times (=*measurement*) looking at several cells (=*roi*) each time.

My aim is to filter out those ROIs of a measurement for all timepoints, that have a intensity value higher than my set threshold at timepoint 0 (I considers these ROIs pre-activated).

```
 data = {  "timepoint": [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3], 
           "measurement": [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
           "roi":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
           "value":[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],
           "group": "control"
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

returns

```
  timepoint     measurement     roi     value   group
0   0                 1          1       0.1    control
1   1                 1          1       0.2    control
2   2                 1          1       0.3    control
3   3                 1          1       0.4    control
4   0                 1          2       0.1    control
5   1                 1          2       0.2    control
6   2                 1          2       0.3    control
7   3                 1          2       0.4    control
8   0                 1          3       0.5    control
9   1                 1          3       0.6    control
10  2                 1          3       0.8    control
11  3                 1          3       0.9    control
12  0                 2          1       0.1    control
13  1                 2          1       0.2    control
14  2                 2          1       0.3    control
15  3                 2          1       0.4    control
16  0                 3          1       0.5    control
17  1                 3          1       0.6    control
18  2                 3          1       0.8    control
19  3                 3          1       0.9    control
20  0                 3          2       0.1    control
21  1                 3          2       0.2    control
22  2                 3          2       0.3    control
23  3                 3          2       0.4    control
```

Now I can select the rows containing ROIs with a value at timepoint 0 higher than my threshold with

```
    threshold = 0.4
    pre_activated = df.loc[(df['timepoint'] == 0) & (df['value'] > threshold)]
    pre_activated
```

which returns

```
timepoint   measurement     roi     value   group
8   0            1           3       0.5    control
16  0            3           1       0.5    control
```

Now I want to filter out those cells (e.g. measurement 1, roi 3) for all timepoints 0 to 3 from the original dataframe `df` - this is the point I am stuck right now.

If I use `.isin`

```
df.loc[~(df['measurement'].isin(pre_activated["measurement"]) & df['roi'].isin(pre_activated["roi"]))]
```

I'll get close but also everything with the `measurement 1` and `roi 1` pair is missing (so I assume it is a problem with the condition expression)

```
   timepoint       measurement    roi    value      group
4   0                   1          2      0.1       control
5   1                   1          2      0.2       control
6   2                   1          2      0.3       control
7   3                   1          2      0.4       control
12  0                   2          1      0.1       control
13  1                   2          1      0.2       control
14  2                   2          1      0.3       control
15  3                   2          1      0.4       control
20  0                   3          2      0.1       control
21  1                   3          2      0.2       control
22  2                   3          2      0.3       control
23  3                   3          2      0.4       control
```

I know I can use `.query` for at least a single measurement & roi pair

```
df[~df.isin(df.query('measurement == 1 & roi == 3'))]
```

which will bring somewhat close, although all integers are converted to float. In addition the "group" column is now NaN, which would make it difficult when there are multiple groups with multiple measurements and rois per dataframe

```
   timepoint    measurement          roi     value  group
    0   0.0                   1.0        1.0     0.1    control
    1   1.0                   1.0        1.0     0.2    control
    2   2.0                   1.0        1.0     0.3    control
    3   3.0                   1.0        1.0     0.4    control
    4   0.0                   1.0        2.0     0.1    control
    5   1.0                   1.0        2.0     0.2    control
    6   2.0                   1.0        2.0     0.3    control
    7   3.0                   1.0        2.0     0.4    control
    8   NaN                   NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN
    9   NaN                   NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN
    10  NaN                   NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN
    11  NaN                   NaN        NaN     NaN    NaN
    12  0.0                   2.0        1.0     0.1    control
    13  1.0                   2.0        1.0     0.2    control
    14  2.0                   2.0        1.0     0.3    control
    15  3.0                   2.0        1.0     0.4    control
    16  0.0                   3.0        1.0     0.5    control
    17  1.0                   3.0        1.0     0.6    control
    18  2.0                   3.0        1.0     0.8    control
    19  3.0                   3.0        1.0     0.9    control
    20  0.0                   3.0        2.0     0.1    control
    21  1.0                   3.0        2.0     0.2    control
    22  2.0                   3.0        2.0     0.3    control
    23  3.0                   3.0        2.0     0.4    control
```

I tried to use a dict that stores the `measurement`:`roi` pair to avoid any mixup but do not really know whether this would be useful:

```
msmt_list = pre_activated["measurement"].values
roi_list = pre_activated["roi"].values

mydict={}
for i in range(len(msmt_list)):
    mydict[msmt_list[i]]=roi_list[i]
```

output

```
   mydict
    {1: 3, 3: 1}
```

What is the best way to achieve what I would like to do? I would appreciate any input, also in terms of efficency as I usually deal with 3-4 groups with 4-8 measurements and up to 200 ROIs each and usually 360 timepoints.

Thanks!

Edit:
Just to clarify what my desired output dataframes should look like

´df_pre_activated´ (those are the "roi" that have a value higher than my threshold at timepoint 0)

```
  timepoint     measurement     roi     value   group
8   0                 1          3       0.5    control
9   1                 1          3       0.6    control
10  2                 1          3       0.8    control
11  3                 1          3       0.9    control
16  0                 3          1       0.5    control
17  1                 3          1       0.6    control
18  2                 3          1       0.8    control
19  3                 3          1       0.9    control
```

´df_filtered´ (this is basically the initial ´df´ without the data in ´df_pre_activated´ shown above)

```
      timepoint     measurement     roi     value   group
0   0                 1          1       0.1    control
1   1                 1          1       0.2    control
2   2                 1          1       0.3    control
3   3                 1          1       0.4    control
4   0                 1          2       0.1    control
5   1                 1          2       0.2    control
6   2                 1          2       0.3    control
7   3                 1          2       0.4    control
12  0                 2          1       0.1    control
13  1                 2          1       0.2    control
14  2                 2          1       0.3    control
15  3                 2          1       0.4    control
20  0                 3          2       0.1    control
21  1                 3          2       0.2    control
22  2                 3          2       0.3    control
23  3                 3          2       0.4    control
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be the following:

First, we calculate `df_pre_activated_t0` by filtering `df` with the condition:

```py
threshold = 0.4
df_pre_activated_t0 = df[(df['timepoint'] == 0) & (df['value'] > threshold)]
```

`df_pre_activated_t0` looks like this:

```
    timepoint  measurement  roi  value    group
8           0            1    3    0.5  control
16          0            3    1    0.5  control
```

We calculate `df_pre_activated` by merging `df` and `df_pre_activated_t0` (**inner** merge):

```py
df_pre_activated = df.merge(
    df_pre_activated_t0[["measurement", "roi"]], how="inner", on=["measurement", "roi"]
)
```

`df_pre_activated` looks like this:

```
   timepoint  measurement  roi  value    group
0          0            1    3    0.5  control
1          1            1    3    0.6  control
2          2            1    3    0.8  control
3          3            1    3    0.9  control
4          0            3    1    0.5  control
5          1            3    1    0.6  control
6          2            3    1    0.8  control
7          3            3    1    0.9  control
```

To calculate `df_filtered` (`df` without the rows of `df_pre_activated`), we do a **left** merge between `df` and `df_pre_activated` and keep the rows where values are **not** in `df_pre_activated`:

```py
df_filtered = df.merge(
    df_pre_activated,
    how="left",
    on=["timepoint", "measurement", "roi", "value"]
)

df_filtered = df_filtered[pd.isna(df_filtered["group_y"])]
```

`df_filtered` looks like this:

```
    timepoint  measurement  roi  value  group_x group_y
0           0            1    1    0.1  control     NaN
1           1            1    1    0.2  control     NaN
2           2            1    1    0.3  control     NaN
3           3            1    1    0.4  control     NaN
4           0            1    2    0.1  control     NaN
5           1            1    2    0.2  control     NaN
6           2            1    2    0.3  control     NaN
7           3            1    2    0.4  control     NaN
12          0            2    1    0.1  control     NaN
13          1            2    1    0.2  control     NaN
14          2            2    1    0.3  control     NaN
15          3            2    1    0.4  control     NaN
20          0            3    2    0.1  control     NaN
21          1            3    2    0.2  control     NaN
22          2            3    2    0.3  control     NaN
23          3            3    2    0.4  control     NaN
```

Finally, we drop the ***group_y*** column and we set the column names to their original values:

```py
df_filtered.drop("group_y", axis=1, inplace=True)
df_filtered.columns = list(df.columns)
```

`df_filtered` looks like this:

```
    timepoint  measurement  roi  value    group
0           0            1    1    0.1  control
1           1            1    1    0.2  control
2           2            1    1    0.3  control
3           3            1    1    0.4  control
4           0            1    2    0.1  control
5           1            1    2    0.2  control
6           2            1    2    0.3  control
7           3            1    2    0.4  control
12          0            2    1    0.1  control
13          1            2    1    0.2  control
14          2            2    1    0.3  control
15          3            2    1    0.4  control
20          0            3    2    0.1  control
21          1            3    2    0.2  control
22          2            3    2    0.3  control
23          3            3    2    0.4  control
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of the .merge function in this context - really helpful! But how would I get the *filtered* dataframe (so the original `df` missing everything in `df2`)? I tried `df[~df.isin(df2)].dropna()` (see [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37227/how-to-remove-rows-from-a-data-frame-that-are-identical-to-other-df) but this did not work..

Comment: You're welcome, I'm happy to help. Do you want to drop exact full rows? Or only rows of `df` where "measurement" and "roi" are in `df2`?

Comment: I'd like to remove all rows  in ´df´ with the measurement and roi pair of ´df2´. So basically ´df´ lacking ´df2´ (see ´df_filtered´ at the very end of my question)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have edited my response. Please let me know if now it's okay.

Comment: Hi Jose  - thank you! The code works well now. The merging steps just takes quite a long time (2min 15s with the initital df having roughly 75000 rows and 5 columns). Also thanks to @Vioxini for your input - I'll try out your way but since it also requires merging I guess it will perform similar to Jose's solution.

Comment: Hi @LukeSkywalker. You're welcome, I'm glad to hear it works. I think for 75,000 rows, 2 minutes is too long, but usually a merge works faster than other things like iterating the rows or the `apply` function in some situations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as this:

In:

```
df[(df["measurement"] != 1) | (df["roi"] != 3)]
```

Out:

```
timepoint   measurement     roi     value   group
0   0   1   1   0.1     control
1   1   1   1   0.2     control
2   2   1   1   0.3     control
3   3   1   1   0.4     control
4   0   1   2   0.1     control
5   1   1   2   0.2     control
6   2   1   2   0.3     control
7   3   1   2   0.4     control
12  0   2   1   0.1     control
13  1   2   1   0.2     control
14  2   2   1   0.3     control
15  3   2   1   0.4     control
16  0   3   1   0.5     control
17  1   3   1   0.6     control
18  2   3   1   0.8     control
19  3   3   1   0.9     control
20  0   3   2   0.1     control
21  1   3   2   0.2     control
22  2   3   2   0.3     control
23  3   3   2   0.4     control
```

This happens due to mathematical logic thinking. You are thinking. Show me the dataframe where a is not 1 and b is not 3, which is the same as show me the dataframe where not a is 1 or b is 3, which removes both 1 and 3 from the dataframe.

You must use a is not 1 or b is not 3, which is the same as not a is 1 and b is not 3.

Hope this helped. In one line.

Edit: To remove both 1 : 3 and 3 : 1, use the AND condition with the both OR conditions:

```
df[((df["measurement"] != 1) | (df["roi"] != 3)) & ((df["measurement"] != 3) | (df["roi"] != 1))]
```

Edit2: To remove directly the filtered rows, you can use the inverse of first filtering and then removing.

In:

```
threshold = 0.4
full_activated = df5[(df5['timepoint'] != 0) | (df5['value'] < threshold)]
full_activated
```

Out:

```
    timepoint   measurement     roi     value   group
0   0   1   1   0.1     control
1   1   1   1   0.2     control
2   2   1   1   0.3     control
3   3   1   1   0.4     control
4   0   1   2   0.1     control
5   1   1   2   0.2     control
6   2   1   2   0.3     control
7   3   1   2   0.4     control
9   1   1   3   0.6     control
10  2   1   3   0.8     control
11  3   1   3   0.9     control
12  0   2   1   0.1     control
13  1   2   1   0.2     control
14  2   2   1   0.3     control
15  3   2   1   0.4     control
17  1   3   1   0.6     control
18  2   3   1   0.8     control
19  3   3   1   0.9     control
20  0   3   2   0.1     control
21  1   3   2   0.2     control
22  2   3   2   0.3     control
23  3   3   2   0.4     control
```

Edit 3:

Multiple conditions

```
threshold = 0.4
full_activated = df5[((df5['timepoint'] != 0) | (df5['value'] < threshold)) & ((df5["measurement"] != 1) | (df5["roi"] != 3)) & ((df5["measurement"] != 3) | (df5["roi"] != 1)) & ((df5["measurement"] != 1) | (df5["roi"] != 1)) ]
full_activated
```

Output:

```
timepoint   measurement     roi     value   group
4   0   1   2   0.1     control
5   1   1   2   0.2     control
6   2   1   2   0.3     control
7   3   1   2   0.4     control
12  0   2   1   0.1     control
13  1   2   1   0.2     control
14  2   2   1   0.3     control
15  3   2   1   0.4     control
20  0   3   2   0.1     control
21  1   3   2   0.2     control
22  2   3   2   0.3     control
23  3   3   2   0.4     control
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer - it helped in terms of the logic thinking behind the condition! But how would I go about multiple `measurement` `roi` pairs?

Comment: Edited answer. You can explain what you want clearer. @LukeSkywalker

Comment: The example is a very very simplified version of the data I have. So how would I filter out those cells if I have a lot of "measurement":"roi" pairs (so not only `"measurement" 1 : "roi" 3` but 30 of such pairs). I updated my question trying to make it a bit clearer!

Comment: Edited again. I could do what you mean, just create a list from measurement and a list for roi, then select all parameters with a loop and merge them.

Comment: Thank you for your input :-). I will give it a try and see whether this performs better than the solution presented by Jose

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Jose A. Jimenez and @Vioxini for their answers. I went with Jose's suggestion and it gives me the output I wanted. I further improved performance using `dask`

```
inputdf.shape
(73124, 5)
```

Using only pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
threshold = 0.4
pre_activated_t0 = inputdf[(inputdf['timepoint'] == 0) & (inputdf['value'] > threshold)]
    
pre_activated = inputdf.merge(pre_activated_t0[["measurement", "roi"]], how="inner", on=["measurement", "roi"])
filtereddf = inputdf.merge(
    pre_activated,
    how="left",
    on=["timepoint", "measurement", "roi", "value"],  
    )
filtereddf = filtereddf[pd.isna(filtereddf["group_y"])]
filtereddf.drop("group_y", axis=1, inplace=True)
filtereddf.columns = list(inputdf.columns)
```

takes 2min 9 seconds.

Now with `dask`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
threshold = 0.4
pre_activated_t0 = inputdf[(inputdf['timepoint'] == 0) & (inputdf['value'] > threshold)]   
pre_activated = inputdf.merge(pre_activated_t0[["measurement", "roi"]], how="inner", on=["measurement", "roi"])

input_dd = dd.from_pandas(inputdf, npartitions=3)
pre_dd = dd.from_pandas(pre_activated, npartitions=3)

merger = dd.merge(input_dd,pre_dd, how="left", on=["timepoint", "measurement", "roi", "value"])
filtereddf = merger.compute()
filtereddf = filtereddf[pd.isna(filtereddf["group_y"])] 
filtereddf.drop("group_y", axis=1, inplace=True)
filtereddf.columns = list(inputdf.columns)
```

this now only takes 42.6 s :-)

It is my first time using dask so there might be some options I am not aware of that could further improve speed, but for now that is ok.

Thanks again for the help!

Edit:

I played around with the `npartitions` option when converting the `pandas dataframe` to a `dask dataframe` and increasing it from 3 to `npartitions=30` further improves performance: it now takes only 9.87 seconds.

Comment: This is great, thanks for your feedback. I will consider using Dask in future situations.